# getCustomAttribute() not working on collection items

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, collection

If I pull a list of products with the repository I am unable to get any custom attributes.

```
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('type_id', 'simple', 'eq')->create();
    $simpleProdSearch = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    $simpleProds = $simpleProdSearch->getItems();

    foreach($simpleProds as $product)
    {
        $cats = $product->getCustomAttribute('category_ids'); // null
    }
```

If I load the product by ID then it works:

```
    foreach($simpleProds as $product)
    {
        $fullProduct = $this->productRepository->getById( $product->getId() );
        $cats = $fullProduct->getCustomAttribute('category_ids');
    }
```

But this loads the product twice.  I am performing action on all products so I want this to be performant as possible.  Can I add the category IDs to the full collection of products?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
$cats= $product->getResource()->getAttribute('category_ids')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Comment: Isn't that doing the same thing and loading product again?

Comment: @Guerrilla can you elaborate what you want.. you need to get product custom attribute value right?

Comment: Im trying to get the custom attribute data in the collection so I can loop over it quickly without database calls on each loop.  Loading product again is a waste as I have already loaded it in intial collection.